# Установленной или установленному?

Tags: орфография, согласование

Данным письмом обращаемся к Вам по вопросу предоставления видеозаписи камеры, установленной над банкоматом, находящегося по адресу...

Comment: Правильно: находящимся по адресу.

Comment: установленной над правильно?

Comment: А что камера - это он? Если так, то будет - установленному. Начинаете учить русский?

Answer (score 1):

Данным письмом обращаемся к Вам по вопросу предоставления видеозаписи с [добавлен предлог] камеры, (какой?) установленной над банкоматом, (каким?) находящимся по адресу...

Ух, сколько канцеляризма!
Можно ведь и попроще, и покороче — а смысл будет тот же.
Настоящим просим Вас предоставить видеозапись с камеры, установленной...
Обращаемся к Вам с просьбой предоставить видеозапись с камеры, установленной...

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам